# conditional operation on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, lambda

my goal is to add a column to the dataframe based on a condition that takes values from other columns into account.

I have created a simple example that generates the same error:

```
numbers = {'A': [1,2,3,4,5], "B":[2,4,3,3,2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(numbers)

if df.A - df.B > 0:
    df["C"] = df.B*5
else: df["C"] = 0
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I am sure the solution is simple but I am a beginner. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c = []

for lab, row in df.iterrows():
    curr = 0
    if row['A'] > row['B']:
        curr = row['B'] * 5

    c.append(curr)

df['C'] = c
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#Import pandas module
import pandas as pd

#Lists of data 
list_A = [1,2,3,4,5]
list_B = [2,4,3,3,2]

#Define a dictionary containing lists of data
dictionary = {'A':  list_A,
        'B': list_B}

#Convert the dictionary into DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
data

#New list
data_diff = data.A - data.B 

new_list=[]
for i in data_diff:
    if i > 0:
        new_list.append(i*5)
    else:
        new_list.append(0)

#New dataframe
new_dictionary = {'A':  [1,2,3,4,5],
        'B': [2,4,3,3,2],
        'C': new_list}

new_data=pd.DataFrame(new_dictionary)
new_data
```

A couple of notes: this is my very simple version. For sure, there are many other smarter and more "pythonic" versions. Finally, I think [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/adding-new-column-to-existing-dataframe-in-pandas/) website of tutorials can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy's [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df["C"] = np.where(df["A"] > df["B"], df["B"]*5, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
df["C"] = df.A - df.B

# First turns negative values into 0s
df["C"].mask(df["C"] <= 0, 0, inplace=True)

# Then changes the value as needed if C > 0.
df["C"].mask(df["C"] > 0, df["B"]*5, inplace=True)
```

Comment: but what if he wants the value to be df['B'] * 5 instead of the difference times 5?

Comment: @swordlordswamplord Oops, read the question wrong, thanks for pointing it out! Fixed my answer now. Your answer's a lot more compact though, I definitely prefer yours.

Comment: o wow. didnt even know about the mask method in pandas.